# Azure - Concurrent call limit exceed - Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus

I am receiving message using OnMessage function and max concurrent calls are set to 200. I received the error which is max concurrent calls exceeded on my entity. Unable to find any solution on internet, please help

```
OnMessageOptions messageOptions = new OnMessageOptions();
messageOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 200;

subClient.OnMessage(message =>
  {
      // implementation here
  }, messageOptions);
```

Maximum number of concurrent receive requests is exceeded on entity 'TopicName|SubscriberName'. The limit is '5000'. Error code : 50004

Comment: Can you share how this code is hosted? Is it scaled out? Executed using multiple instances of host?

Comment: The code is hosted in web job and the web job is timer triggered.
We have check on starting of web job which is below.
 
if (subClient == null || subClient.IsClosed)
                {
                    subClient = 
SubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(serviceBusConn, topicName, subscriberName);

                    subClient.OnMessage(message =>
                    {
                        // implementation
                    }, messageOptions);

                }